# fltpage out of support?

Tags: packages, miktex, distributions

I created a document with Miktex and TexnicCenter a year ago and it worked fine. Since my pc died I installed everything again (Win8) but now no pdf is produced Because: error file `fltpage.sty` not found.
I already changed the repository, admin mode. Also installed everything on Win7, but no difference. 
Does anyone know if `fltpage` is not longer supported by Miktex?
Is there any good alternative (I have tons of huge figues with long captions).
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fltpage
gives no .cls or.sty file which is supposed to be needed if I install a package manually in Miktex. Is there any manual step- by- step from the really beginning for people that have absolutely no clue?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

If you just look into MikTeX's package repository (https://miktex.org/packages/) you won't find `fltpage`. Hence you have to download and install it manually (e.g. from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fltpage).

*Update:* As Moewe described in the comments `fltpage` is licensed with a "Li­cense that pre­vents dis­tri­bu­tion".

Comment: Ok, I was worried this is the answer and already downloaded the package in the link. is there any manual for installing packages for people that a not at all familiar with that?

Comment: @AMJ Check out https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows. And please accept this answer if it covers all expectations to an answer.

Comment: The reason that this is not in MikTeX or TeX live is probably that CTAN classes the license of the package as 'Li­cense that pre­vents dis­tri­bu­tion'.